# access control for different types of admins with symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

i am working with a symfony1.4 project.In my project there are a super admin and under super admin there are four different admin like Hradmin, finance admin, faculty admin, department admin.These admin has differnt types of menus.

My question is how can i secured one type of admin from another type of admin. as a example, if someone logged with HR admin can not see the finance admin's menus or other pages with the url directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sfGuard plugin to user identity management 
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin

Comment: [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) is better.Read [Day 13: The User](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/13)